How to exclude a single C++ compile definition from the pch compilation in CMake?
I am creating some cross-platform C++ product. One of the platforms is Windows+MSVC but I'm not sure if it matters here. I am using CMake as a build system.
I created a shared library lib which uses pch.h as a precompiled header:
   target_precompile_headers( lib PUBLIC pch.h )

I added an executable exe target that links to lib and decided to take the same already precompiled header for it knowing about the existence of target_precompile_headers+REUSE_FROM option:
target_precompile_headers( exe REUSE_FROM lib )
target_link_libraries( exe lib )

But I am getting a compilation warning from VS:
warning C4651: '/Dlib_EXPORTS' specified for precompiled header but not for current compile

I understand that CMake added this compile definition while building lib. It is convenient for exporting symbols from lib so I'm satisfied with this definition when it is applied to library's *.cpp-files. But as for pch.h I don't need this definition to be applied.

I could suppress this warning but I don't consider that option.
I can create a separate target that would only build the precompiled header and then use this precompiled header in both lib and exe. It works but it seems like extra actions to me: if I have N lib-s and N exe-s, I would need to add N new auxiliary targets like this one.

Is there a way I could tell CMake to exclude this lib_EXPORTS definition only from pch.h compilation call?
I've already tried some things like set_source_files_properties(pch.h ...) but I haven't succeeded.
UPD. Minimal example:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(pch_extra_def)
add_library(lib SHARED lib.cpp)
target_precompile_headers( lib PUBLIC pch.h )

add_executable(exe exe.cpp)
target_precompile_headers( exe REUSE_FROM lib )
target_link_libraries( exe lib )
set_target_properties( exe PROPERTIES COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON )

pch.h
#include <iostream>

lib.h
#ifdef lib_EXPORTS
#define lib_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define lib_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


lib_API void f();

lib.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "lib.h"

void f()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello, ";
}

exe.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "lib.h"

void main()
{
    f();
    std::cout<<"World!"<<std::endl;
}


You should make lib_EXPORTS as a PUBLIC define for lib

@qz can you please explain? I don't need exe target to define lib_EXPORTS

You do because it changes the meaning of lib.h which is included from your exe.

Add pch.cpp
#include "pch.h"

And update CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(pch_extra_def CXX)

add_library(pch STATIC pch.cpp)
target_precompile_headers( pch PUBLIC pch.h )

add_library(lib SHARED lib.cpp)
target_precompile_headers( lib REUSE_FROM pch )

add_executable(exe exe.cpp)
target_precompile_headers( exe REUSE_FROM pch )
target_link_libraries( exe lib )
set_target_properties( exe PROPERTIES COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON )


if I have N lib-s and N exe-s, I would need to add N new auxiliary targets like this one.

No, unless you use own/different pch.h in each shared lib.

thank you for the proposed solution. unfortunately using the only pch.h for all those N libs is too tough of a restriction. so is providing each library with a satellite pch-library the simplest way to achieve what I want? isn't there a solution allowing to have my own flags for PCH compilation within the lib target?

Why do you want to use their PCHs? Your apps are using distinct sets of #include. IMHO it looks like the XY problem.

right, the question is simplified. in real life product we have multiple shared libs of predefined structure, all of them declared with the same cmake macro, which in addition looks for pch.h in a library's dir (different one for each lib). I wanted to use the same pch in exe because it is already there precompiled. any solution inevitably leads to modifying the macro. but adding new targets would result in them flooding the build log and creating the excessive choice of targets to build (1.5 times more options). I'd like to avoid producing O(N) targets and get flexible PCHs that can be reused

You can't re-use PCH of a shared lib if an app uses different set of defined macros.

If you can get rid of #define lib_API and can use lib.def I can show another solution.

@soad: It still looks like the XY problem. Why do you ever want to use precompiled headers? The only advantage of that feature is slightly improved compile time. In exchange, a precompiled header has highly reduced reusability. When talk about large projects, reusability and scalability becomes much more important than "very fast build".

thank you for your reply. do you mean that using precompiled headers only makes sense in small size products?
